# gitlab 6.6.5 community centos rpm - can't figure out how to launch rails console

Tags: gitlab

Environment:

OS: Centos 6.5

GitLab: gitlab-6.6.5_omnibus-1.el6.x86_64.rpm (installed as root user)

Hello all,

I am attempting to figure out how to launch rails console for the gitlab application so I can take a look a the data as needed.

Based on what I read in the documentation it should be stored in /home/git/gitlab but when I change to my git user there isn't a gitlab directory. I did see that there is something familiar in /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails but since I am logged in as root I don't seem to have anything in my path to execute.

Should I not have installed this as root since all of the documentation for installation is using sudo? If I do have to use something other than root for the install, is simply uninstalling the RPM good enough or do I need to re-install the entire OS?

If my system is ok being installed as root, can anyone tell me where I can find the documentation related to administering gitlab or at the very least the documentation on how to view the data? The documentation that I have found is as of version 5 and it doesn't look like it applies to 6. Again I could be wrong if I installed this incorrectly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little disappointed that there doesn't appear to be any documentation for how to install gitlab from RPM, however, I think I've managed to figure it out.

1. Download and install the .rpm for Centos from https://www.gitlab.com/downloads/
2. Run: /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-ctl reconfigure
3. Browse to http://example.com:80 and log in with the following creds:

   username: admin@local.host
   password: 5iveL!fe

I would be cautious of using the above steps for deploying a production site (especially one exposed to the internet) because many of the services seem to be running as root. I'll be doing a bit more reading to see if I can restrict this further.

Also, configuration looks like it's located under: /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc.

Good luck!

Bowen

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old question, but the answer is:

```
sudo gitlab-rake rails console
```